# How to make material design imagery with GIMP

Tags: gimp, images, google-material-design

all.

I want to create material design imagery for my website, but don't have flashy tools like Photoshop or Illustrator. However, I do have GIMP 2 on Ubuntu. Examples of material design imagery can be seen below:
 [image: Material design image 1]
and
[image: Material design image 2]
Any answers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What part are you especially not able to do?

Comment: Sharp edges and flat colors:  better use vector graphics (ie, Inkscape)

Comment: Depends on your drawing skills. When you cannot draw these sort of things with pen and paper you won't be able to do so with "flashy" software.

Comment: @RadLexus The noise effect that is very present in the top one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need "flashy" tools. You can do flat design even in Microsoft Paint, which is the simplest program ever.

You can simply use the Path tool to make a shape, convert it to a selection and fill it with a color or gradient. [Here's a tutorial](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Drawing_Shapes/).

But in reality using GIMP is the wrong approach. You should use a vector based program, such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/shapes/tutorial-shapes.html).

These kinds of images are based on simple geometric shapes, so just pay attention to what you want to do. Imagine a Sesame Street program. "Where do I find a triangle? Let's go find me a triangle".